# Javascript Count HTML Column Values

Tags: javascript, html

Using Javascript within an HTML page, is it possible to count the instances of a given text value in the cells for a given column?  In other words, if one of the columns contains cell values of either "1" or "2", can I generate a "total" count of how many "2" values exist in that column?

Comment: Are you looking for the total in a column or row? You refer to both in your question.

Comment: Both answers to this question (as of writing) feature a jQuery-based implementation of JavaScript. Are you using a library at all, or do you require plain JavaScript?

Comment: @David: You're right. Somehow I thought I saw a jQuery tag. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** *Regarding your comment:*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cGS99/

```
var rows = document.getElementById('myTable').rows,
    len = rows.length,
    i,
    cellNum = 0,
    count = 0,
    cell;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cell = rows[i].cells[cellNum];
    if (cell.innerHTML === 'X') {
        count++;
    } else if(cell.innerHTML === '...') {
        cell.innerHTML = count;
    }
}
```

*or if by the column with "...", you meant the last column, change this:*

```
    } else if(cell.innerHTML === '...') {
```

*to this:*

```
    } else if(i === (len - 1)) {
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cGS99/1/

---

*doh!*

---

```
var rows = document.getElementById('myTable').rows, // get the rows in the table
    len = rows.length,    // get the quantity of rows
    cell = 1,             // index of the column (zero based index)
    count = 0;            // keep score

while( len-- ) {
    if( rows[len].cells[cell].innerHTML.indexOf('2') > -1 )
        count++;
}
```

This will work as long as the content doesn't have possible sub-strings of "2", like "12".

Comment: As I always trust your answers, I am a bit confused that you posted a jQuery answer to a JavaScript question. Do I miss something? Did the OP change tags in the 5 minute span?

Comment: @Felix: Cuz JQUERY makes teh best codez!!!!!!! *(actually, I could have sworn I saw the tag)* Updated. Thanks for the note. :o)

Comment: @Felix: Just caught the `innerHTML` but missed the `#`. I'll update. Thanks. :o) I'm just way off today.

Comment: @patrick, and the *other* (as of writing) +1 from me, basically for the *doh!* and, of course, for the edited answer.

Comment: @patrick...well, you're already at > 47k. I'm not rewarding you for **all** of your *doh!* s... =D

Comment: Ok, I need to clarify a bit...  <table><tr><td>X</td><td></td><tr><td>Y</td></tr><tr><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>   What I really need is to be able to replace the cell with "..." to show an integer indicating how may "X" values appear in that column.

Comment: ...oh, I see you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Apqy/).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Use length

```
$('td:contains(1)').length
$('td:contains(2)').length
```

Output:

```
--> 4
--> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

@patrick_dw pointed me in the direction I needed (thanks!).  Here's the result that works for me...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title></title>
<script language="Javascript">
function getx() {
    var rows = document.getElementById('myTable').rows, // get the rows in the table
    len = rows.length,    // get the quantity of rows
    cell = 0,             // index of the column (zero based index)
    count = 0;            // keep score

    while( len-- ) {
        if( rows[len].cells[cell].innerHTML.indexOf('1') > -1 )
            count++;
    }
    document.getElementById('colx').innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="getx();">

<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="colx"> </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```